# Почему writeObject() кидает NotSerializableException?

Tags: java, serializable

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main implements Serializable { 

    private int width;
    private int size;

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setWidth(22);
        m.setSize(84);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("andriy.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objectOut.writeObject(objectOut);
            objectOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**UPD. Пропустил, что нужно было передать ссылку на экземпляр класса Main**

> ObjectOutputStream не реализует Serializable, поэтому, наверное. Вообще строка objectOut.writeObject(objectOut); выглядит странно. – zRrr

[Скриншот из Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB167.png)

Answer (score 3):

`objectOut.writeObject(objectOut);`

Вы хотите, чтобы объект для записи сериализованных объектов записал сам себя? Если подходить более формально, то:

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams

Класс `ObjectOutputStream` не реализует интерфейс `java.io.Serializable`, отсюда и исключение.

Скорее всего, вы хотели написать:

`objectOut.writeObject(m);`